# How can I bind multiple checkboxes to a list in Play framework?

Tags: forms, binding, playframework

I have a list of checkboxes in a form that is based on some already existing objects in the system, like this:

```
#{list items:foobars, as:'bar'}
    <div>
        #{set name:"foo.bars[" + bar_index + "]" /}
        <label for="${bar.name}">${bar.name}</label>
        <input id="${bar.name}" name="${name}" type="checkbox">
    </div>
#{/list}
```

I would like Play to bind them to the list of Bar objects that Foo object should contain. (Foo and Bar has a many-to-many-relationship)

This doesn't work. How can I do this with Play?

Answer (score 2):

In my case i resorted to the old Long collection binding, i've been unable to make bindind of JPA associated collections using the id suggested naming of fields: Use the next collection for binding the id's selected on the web form:

```
Set<Long> bars
```

Keep in mind that if there is no checkbox selected the collection may be null and not zero length, so the validation code should look:

```
if (bars == null || bars.size() == 0)
   validation.addError("bars", "Please selecta at least one bar");
```

Latter on, in the controller handler you should instanciate bars with JPA find by id, and add to foo's collection:

```
for (Long id : bars)
   foo.bars.add((Bar) Bar.findById(id));
```

Bye
Hans